# Determine the elements of a set, so that their mean, median and standard deviation are all equal to 3.

Tags: statistics

> Determine the elements of a set, so that their mean, median and standard deviation are all equal to 3. The set has 3 elements, all elements are real numbers.

I have already figured it out, that one of the numbers is 3, as their mean is 3 and there are only 3 numbers in the set.

Comment: how do you define dispersion?

Comment: I was referring to standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the numbers $a,b,c$ and without loss of generality assume $a<b<c$. We see right away that $$b = 3$$ since $b$ is the median. Now, $$\frac{a+b+c}{3} = 3 \Rightarrow a+3+c = 9 \Rightarrow a+c = 6$$

Now using standard deviation,

$$\sigma = 3= \sqrt{\frac{(a-3)^2+(3-3)^2+(c-3)^2}{3}}$$
$$\Rightarrow 27 = (a-3)^2+(c-3)^2$$

You now have a system of two equations only involving $a$ and $c$,

$$a+c = 6  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$27 = (a-3)^2+(c-3)^2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

so you can find their values.

Comment: It eases calculations to notice the set is $(x-3,x,x+3)$.